# Parsing JSON from web service using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, web-services

i am using a web service to get some statistical info. the web service is getting the result is JSON format.

i use the following jquery to get the result from the web service:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: webMethod,
    //data: parameters,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (json) {
        console.log(json);
        var obj = $.parseJSON(json);
        alert(obj.Admin_3_New);
    }
})
```

the log looks like this:

```
Object {d: "{"Admin_3_New":6,"Admin_3_ReNew":2,"NewFinalApprov…val":19,"VisitCount_All":25,"VisitCount_Today":0}"}
```

when ever i try to parse the returned JSON it gets null.

any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Your data should look like this to make it work:

```
{d: {Admin_3_New:6,Admin_3_ReNew:2,NewFinalApproval:19,VisitCount_All:25,VisitCount_Today:0}};
```

Get rid of double quotes ("") on curly braces and that should resolve your issue.

To test it, you can try running below code in your browser console:

```
var test = {d: {Admin_3_New:6,Admin_3_ReNew:2,NewFinalApproval:19,VisitCount_All:25,VisitCount_Today:0}};
```

You'll be able to access values without parsing the object into JSON i.e. test.d.Admin_3_New //this would return '6'

**EDITED ANSWER:**

```
var data = 'Object {d: "{"Admin_3_New":6,"Admin_3_ReNew":2,"NewFinalApprov…val":19,"VisitCount_All":25,‌​"VisitCount_Today":0}"}'; 
data = data.replace('Object {d: ',''); 
data = data.substring(1, data.length - 2); 
var parsedValue = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Comment: Note that the OP has copy+pasted from the console, hence the odd formatting of the object in his example. If the response really looked like that, it wouldn't have `Object` at the start of it.

Comment: it does have 'object' at the start of it. please review the question

Comment: how do i remove the quotes ("") on curly braces

Comment: Why are you having curly braces in double quotes?

Comment: it is returned from the web service

Comment: I think you're sending a string from your server side code. Best would be to exclude the quotes from the server. Once that is done, you'll be able to parse it to JSON.

Comment: @NishitVaghela did you find any ideas. By the way i use Newtonsoft.Json to parse the objects

Comment: var data = 'Object {d: "{"Admin_3_New":6,"Admin_3_ReNew":2,"NewFinalApprov…val":19,"VisitCount_All":25,"VisitCount_Today":0}"}';

data = data.replace('Object {d: ','');
data = data.substring(1, data.length - 2);
var parsedValue = $.parseJSON(data);

Comment: I've edited my answer above. Let me know if that works.

Comment: thank you @NishitVaghela i found out that i am doing it wrongly as i do not have to create a json of the object in the service code it self and the .net framework do all the trick and i can read the result as JSON from javascript directly. in short the problem was i was making a json of a json that is all.

Comment: glad, you figured out the solution. Cheers.